# Angular PWA: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility'

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I've been trying to put the following command:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

However, I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility'
```

I tried installing @schematics using NPM, but it doesn't work and I can't find further information about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer in a Github issue. My environment version is:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 14.17.4
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.3.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.7
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.1
@angular/cdk                    13.3.9
@angular/cli                    13.3.7
@angular/material               13.3.9
@angular/pwa                    14.0.1
@nguniversal/builders           13.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.1.1
@schematics/angular             9.1.13
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4
```

In this case, we need to use this specific command:

```
ng add @angular/pwa@13
```

The Github post is https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23343